# How to get ble receive data in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to receive data through ble in android

With the two basic examples below, the ble connection was successful.

But I did not succeed in receiving the data

https://github.com/googlearchive/android-BluetoothLeGatt
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le?hl=ko

What's even weirder is that the data comes in after launching the nRF Connect app
(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp)
I need to fix something in the app, but I haven't been able to find that part for days
Which part do you need to fix?
thank you

Comment: Did you see that the android-BluetoothLeGatt repository was migrated into connectivity-samples repo by android? You can find the current version [here](https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/main/BluetoothLeGatt)

Comment: Do you mind to show what you've implemented so far? Have yo implemented a `BluetoothGattCallback` properly? Programming for BLE is a little hard for its asynchronous nature, as well as the API mess of Android.

Comment: Michael Kotzjan thanks for the reply i tried this too

Comment: Mr. Kozmotronik, I used the source from the link below almost as it is. Only the device scan part was slightly modified. Please understand that the source is long and cannot be uploaded.